# XML file encryption

Tags: android, xml, encryption

I am creating an XML file data using XML Serializer methods. The XML file is created and stored on the SDCard when custom events occur. I need to encrypt this file while storing it on SDCard and later Decrypt it when the user hits the button.

I want to encrypt and decrypt the XML file as a whole because data stored in XML file is large. So, is there a way to encrypt and decrypt the XML file as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use RSA to encrypt anything larger than the key size (typically 1024-4096 *bits*). For large data, you need to use a block (or stream) cipher, such as AES. You need to use the `Cipher` class with a suitable mechanism such as 'AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding'. As usual, the bigger problem is where and how to store the key.

What are you trying to achieve? Who/what are you trying to protect your data from? What level of protection do you need?

Comment: I am trying to Encrypt and Decrypt the created XML file (on SDCard) as a whole.I want to achieve single time encryption and decryption mechanism for the XML file. Since i am storing the XML file on SDcard, i dont want to let the user any information even if it's copied fro SDcard.

Comment: Should they be able to read it (via the app) if they copy it to another phone (all apps sharing the same key)? Do they even need to know it's encrypted?

Comment: There is no need to read it via app. The Encrypted XML file will be posted to the Server.The Decryption of the file should be done on the Server. There is no need for the user to know the file is encrypted.

Comment: In that case, consider using SSL to talk to your server, and do not store the file on the SD card at all.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong info. We need not upload the encrypted file. Can u plz let me know if there is a way to encrypt and decrypt an XML file as a single unit?

Comment: Consider editing your question. It is still unclear what you need to do. You need to be clear on: who creates the file? who uses the file? who do they communicate?. As for your question, as I said, you need to use the `Cipher` class. You can encrypt/decrypt in a single operation using [`doFinal`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal(byte[])). This may not be practical if the file size is large.